# MySQL: Get the datetime field with time part reset to midnight (00:00:00)?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am trying to query the `PurchaseDate` datetime column from `tmp` table along with a custom column that is `PurchaseDate` column with time as 00:00:00 / midnight:

| PurchaseDate | StartOfDay |
| --- | --- |
| 1996-07-16 20:00:00 | 1996-07-16 00:00:00 |
| 1996-07-10 21:19:00 | 1996-07-10 00:00:00 |
| 1996-07-12 22:18:00 | 1996-07-12 00:00:00 |

I wasn't able to do it using `DATEDIFF()`. How can I do it in the simplest way?

As suggested, I have tried using `date()`. However that converts the column type to date and I would like to retain it as a datetime.

Comment: `select purchaseDate, date(purchaseDate) startOfDay from mytable`

Comment: @Bohemian ♦ That converts the column type to date. I want to retain the field as a datetime.

Comment: *That converts the column type to date.* ??? No. This converts the **value** got for a column to DATE datatype, and hence zeroes the time part. The column in a table stays unchanged.

Comment: *I wasn't able to do it using DATEDIFF().** Why do you think so? `DATEDIFF()` cuts off the timeparts from both operands then substracts the dates. [DATEDIFF() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff): *DATEDIFF() returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. **Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.***

Comment: @Akina, sorry I didn't mean that it converts the column type to date, but the end result for the custom column is displayed as date, whereas I needed it in datetime format. As you said for `datediff()` it uses only the date parts, but I needed even the time portion to be considered although it is `00:00:00`. But I have used Bohemian's solution for now. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to `date` to truncate the time part, then cast to `datetime`:

```
select
    PurchaseDate,
    cast(date(PurchaseDate) as datetime) as StartOfDay
from mytable
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/247075).

Comment: I've tried this too, but I was guessing that this might be a hacky way to do it. I just wanted to be sure that this is the best approach, as I would be querying large dataset using this operation.

Comment: @NikhilPNaik are you searching for rows using the midnight value in a `where` clause, or are you just selecting it like this?

Comment: ♦, I am not filtering by midnight value. Just need to select it using inbuilt functions. The one that you shared works well, but just wanted an advise on performance, in case if there is an index on datetime column.